# Objective-C Delegate Memory Storage null Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I've been having trouble with a delegate between two `UIViewController`s in Objective-C.

I've created the delegate in one of the `UIViewController`s that talks back to the previous `UIViewController`. I declared the delegate as such in the `ConfirmDetailsViewController`. (This was declared in the `viewDidLoad`, along with the rest of the delegate code):

```
ForthViewController *delegate = [[ForthViewController alloc] init];
```

I've also included the correct `#import "ForthViewController.h"` above the `@interface` of the `.m` file.

A few lines later in the I'm setting a group of local property `NSString`s to the value of `delegate.nameString`, which is another group of property `NSString`s from the `ForthViewController`, as such:

```
self.nameString = delegate.nameString;
self.emailAddressString = delegate.emailAddressString;
self.phoneNumberString = delegate.phoneNumberString;
self.emergencyPhoneNumberString = delegate.emergencyPhoneNumberString;
self.additionalDonationString = delegate.additionalDonationString;
```

I then go on to print the values of `self.nameString`, `self.emailAddressString`, etc to the console with `NSLog` as such:

```
NSLog(@"Name: %@", self.nameString);
NSLog(@"Email Address: %@", self.emailAddressString);
NSLog(@"Phone Number: %@", self.phoneNumberString);
NSLog(@"Emergency Phone Number: %@", self.emergencyPhoneNumberString);
NSLog(@"Donation: $%@", self.additionalDonationString);
```

In the `ForthViewController` after assigning the values of the local property objects to `self.nameString`, etc. I print their values to the console and get the appropriate values. When I then transfer the objects to the `ConfirmDetailsViewController`, I'm confronted with `(null)` values for all of the strings.

I believe the most likely fault is in how the delegate is declared in the `ConfirmDetailsViewController`, however I've seen multiple sources online that say this is how you setup the delegate. How would I get the proper values to siphon through the delegate properly without loosing their values and resetting to `null`?

In case you had trouble with my explanation, here is a download link to a sample project where this issue is apparent: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/66x89dciu4waxyd/AADdA3ehUglWIDWZGzG08zqpa

**EDIT**

For those who were wondering, this is how I declared the `NSString` properties in both the `.h` file of `ForthViewController` and `.h` file of `ConfirmDetailsViewController`:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *nameString;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *emailAddressString;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *additionalDonationString;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *phoneNumberString;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *emergencyPhoneNumberString;
```

Comment: So `ForthViewController` is on the screen and then `ConfirmDetails` is presented, is that correct?  If so, how are you presenting `ConfirmDetails`?

Comment: @user3386109 The `ForthViewController` is presented first, then later, `ConfirmDetailsViewController` is presented.

Comment: You are creating an instance of ForthViewController as a local variable in viewDidLoad which means that as soon as viewDidLoad exits that view controller is released. You actually need your delegate to be a property whose value is assigned when ForthViewController invokes ConfirmDetailsViewController. Also this isn't a delegation pattern as delegation has one object invoking methods on another, typically in response to events - think of a UITableViewDelegate for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you're not getting good values out of the `ForthViewController` because you created it using alloc/init. The object you have as "delegate" is not the same object that has proper values for the properties you want. In the sample project you provided, for instance, the `saveButton:` method would never be called for the object you have set as delegate.

So, how should you set it up? Use the `@protocol` syntax to create a real delegate. Define the protocol in the second view controller's header, and make the first view controller subscribe to that protocol. Then add a `delegate` property of the second view controller that requires its value to conform to the protocol. When you create an instance of the second view controller, set its delegate property to `self` to make the connection. Now, in your second view controller code, you can safely call any of the methods you have listed in the protocol on the delegate object.

**This is a delegation pattern** because the second view controller can dispatch messages to an object that it doesn't know anything about. All it knows is that its delegate can receive its messages.

[Here is the scoop on protocols, straight from the horse's mouth.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html)

Comment: While that makes sense, why would `AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];` work when delegating to the `AppDelegate`?

Comment: Because `sharedApplication` is a class method that returns a singleton http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes

Comment: The `sharedApplication` "instance" of an application keeps a delegate like a secretary. The application tells the delegate what it's doing, and the delegate takes care of any supplementary work. And, the application doesn't have to know anything about the delegate itself to do its job *except* that it can receive the application's messages.